# Add text to textarrea issue using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textarea

There are times tha i feel so frustrated when trying to do simple things with Jquery.
I have a textarea where user can write own things but can also chose from some predefined phrases and add them too

so html looks like

```
<textarea id="id_text"></textarea>
<div id="predef-phrases>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>checkbox1</label> 
    <input type="checkbox"><label>checkbox2</label>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>checkbox3</label>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>checkbox4</label>     
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add phrases" />
```

and the jquery is like this:

```
$(document).read(function(){
      $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#predef-phrases input[type=checkbox").each(function(i, checkbox){
            if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
                text_value = $("#id_text").val();
                checkbox_text = $(checkbox).next('label').text();
                $("#id_text").append(checkbox_text+'\n');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works fine up until the user types some text. Then the predefined phrases are not appended in textarea when user presses the add button. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `append`, which would only change the "initial" value, but directly change the value :

```
$("#id_text")[0].value += checkbox_text+'\n';
```

If you prefer, you may also use the `val` function :

```
$("#id_text").val(function(_,text){ return text+checkbox_text+'\n'});
```

But you also have errors in your HTML (missing closing quote) and in your selector (missing closing brace). [Here's a fixed code](http://jsbin.com/Ugutut/1/).

Comment: This is what i did. I changed append with $("#id_text").val($("#id_text").val()+checkbox_text+'\n');

Comment: your fixed code uses append or val()?Did you just corrected my code? Cause it won't let me add predefined prhases after i type in textarea

Comment: Yes i am sorry...didn't see the phrases needed to scroll...Sorry!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use append() for textarea. Instead you can try the following:

```
$("#id_text").val($("#id_text").val() + '\n' + checkbox_text);
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly how I finally did it. Thank you.